# Photon - OnLeftRoom Called Unexpectedly

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm developing an app for Quest and I'm seeing some strange behaviour.

User 1 joins a room - User 1 is now the masterclient.
User 2 joins the same room.
User 1 now force-closes the application.
User 2 receives an OnPlayerLeftRoom as expected but I also then see an OnRoomLeft being called immediately after even though this isn't the player that disconnected. Its happening due to a Disconnected event being received in LoadBalancingClient.OnStatusChanged() on the following lines:

```
if (this.Server == ServerConnection.GameServer && wasInRoom)
{
    this.MatchMakingCallbackTargets.OnLeftRoom();
}
```

I can see that OnMasterClientSwitched is called in the Client first and I would've expected this user to become the master but then the OnRoomLeft is called which is unexpected.

Is this normal?